# Page unable to get the type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, types, react-props

This is the page that I am using to display the images, I thought there is something else is wrong with my code. I removed a lot of things and I just realized that props is empty when I print using console.log.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

type typeName = 'logo' | 'Admin' | 'Delete' | 'User';

type svgProps = {
  name: typeName,
  resource: String,
  getImage: Function,
};

const Svg = (props: svgProps) => {
  console.log("Props is Empty:", props)
  if (props.resource) {
    return (
      <img style={props.style} src={props.resource.default} />
    )
  }
  switch (props.name) {
    case 'logo':
      return (
        <img style={props.style} />
      )
    default:
      return <Typography>Not Found</Typography>;
  }
};

Svg.propsType = {
  name: String,
  resource: Object,
};

export { Svg }
export default Svg;
```

This Svg component is exported and then I use them in Routes to load it. I can see the component is exported properly and I can see the page loading fine. Only thing which I couldn't figure out is why the props is empty. Even if I have button & print the props, its printing as empty. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show how you use this `<Svg>` component

Comment: @Konrad, Thank you. I have it loaded under <Router><Container><Routes><Route>. The page loads fine, I can see it's loaded without any error. So you think there is no issue with this code rather how we load the components?

Comment: Props is most likely empty because you didn't pass any props

Comment: I mean, I am not expecting the values here. But I expect the props would print the things inside the type. Like what the props hold , right now it shows only [[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: I am using similar code in another screen where I can see the same log prints like name: 
null
resource
: 
undefined
getName
: 
function